# Switching from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I have 12.04LTS installed on my laptop. I want to upgrade it to 14.04LTS. I tried to find a method but didn't succeed. I read somewhere that I can directly upgrade from one LTS to other but how?

Comment: My internet connection is slow. So, I might not be able to download the new version in one go. Is that a big problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remove all 3rd party binary drivers such as `NVIDIA` or `AMD` graphics card driver.

(Because 3rd party drivers only works with current kernel and will not work with newer version. You may see blank screen with older driver version. Hence, remove, update, and reinstall to save time.)

Once removed and rebooted the desktop.Then:

Open terminal by `ctrl+alt+t` .

1. install `update-manager-core` by:

   `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`
2. `upgrade` the newest version by:

   `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Finally, reinstall 3rd party binary drivers.

Comment: `-d` flag is for upgrading to development releases

Comment: if -d is for development releases then what should I give argument.           -f ?          I have seen it somewhere.

Comment: To force upgrade pass the `-d` option to `sudo do-release-upgrade` command.